# How can I create a DF for each iteration in a loop?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to create a small database that stores the schedules for each team in the NFL. I want to create a new DF for each iteration in the loop.

This means that each team would get a new DF for each season. Each new DF would be named the team abbreviation and year of the iteration. For example, IND_2021 or something of the like for the Indianapolis Colts.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

abbreviations = ['IND','LAR','SFO','BUF','LAC','TAM','BAL','CIN','MIN','GNB','KAN','PIT','ARI','DAL','CLE',
                'SEA','NWE','PHI','NOR','WAS','ATL','LVR','TEN','CAR','DEN','MIA','HOU','CHI','DET','JAX','NYG','NYJ']
year = '2021'
list_of_dataframes = []
for team in abbreviations: 
    url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/{}/{}.htm'.format(team,year)
    df = pd.read_html(url)[1]
    df['team'] = team
    list_of_dataframes.append(df)
    
final_df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I've tried a bunch of different potential solutions, but have been stuck on this for a while. I might be on the total wrong path as well, so I would very much appreciate any insight on how to resolve.

Comment: Dataframes don't have names. Maybe you should use a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: It's unclear to me how what you're asking for differs from what the code you give does. Is there something wrong with your current code? It looks to me like it would create a list of dataframes, just like you want. Are you getting some kind of exception? If so, give the traceback.

Comment: Purely from a data/schema perspective, I feel like it would be better to create a single DF with Team Name and Season as their own columns, much the way you would do in an RDBMS. Maybe that's just the DBA in me though.

Comment: HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found is there error that I receive.

Answer (score 0):

1st, you need to fix your url variable based on those team abbreviations. The reason you get `Not Found` error is because it's precisely that...the site you want doesn't exist. Try going to https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/CHI/2021.htm. Those aren't the correct urls. The team abbreviations in the url should be lower case.

Secondly, with that point I just made, some of the team abbreviations aren't correct. `'IND'` should be `'CLT'`, `'LAR'` should be `'RAM'`, etc... there's a few more to correct too.

Thirdly, you can't "name" a dataframe. What you can do as suggested in the comments is create a dictionary of the dataframes. And the key can be the name of the team:

```
import pandas as pd

abbreviations = ['CLT','RAM','SFO','BUF','SDG','TAM','RAV','CIN','MIN','GNB','KAN','PIT','CRD','DAL','CLE',
                'SEA','NWE','PHI','NOR','WAS','ATL','RAI','OTI','CAR','DEN','MIA','HTX','CHI','DET','JAX','NYG','NYJ']
year = '2021'
dict_of_dataframes = {}
for team in abbreviations: 
    print(team)
    url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/{}/{}.htm'.format(team.lower(),year)
    df = pd.read_html(url)[1]
    df['team'] = team
    dict_of_dataframes[f'{team}_{year}'] = df
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting note on the team abbreviations. I actually took a list of players from profootballreference.com and just removed duplicates from the 'Tm' field. This is the link that I used - https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/fantasy.htm. So that's little weird that the abbreviations are wrong.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help! I now want to apply the data cleaning steps into the loop so that the output is cleaner and only includes the data I'm interested in. For example, steps such as renaming columns, dropping columns, etc. Do I just add the steps underneath your last line of code?

Comment: I'd probably do that right after `df = pd.read_html(url)[1]`. But that's just me. Then followed by the last 2 lines of making the `team` column, then appending that into the dictionary

Comment: You have the abbreviations hard coded in, but can the abbreviations be store in a dataframe instead? Meaning, rather than loop through the list of hard coded abbreviations the code would loop through values stored in a dataframe. Would that change my code at all?

Comment: well they are stored in the dataframe when you do `df['team'] = team`. I'm not quite sure what you're asking.